# force python container to stay in "running" state for debugging

Tags: python, dockerfile

Im using the follwoing docker file to run a python script

```
FROM python:3
COPY . /app
RUN pip install requests
RUN mkdir /app/foo
ENTRYPOINT [ "python3", "/app/main.py"]
```

the issue is that a file that need to be created  , dose not created and i cant debug it inside the container it stopped to fast .

each run the contianer dies within 6 sec - i tried:
infinite while loop in the python script .
adding RUN tail -f to docker file with 0 success.

im running  on docker desktop (win 10)

Comment: Can you share the code from `main.py`?

Comment: I've not done work with docker myself, but my first questions are:  1) Does your Python program run correctly *outside* docker? and 2) Can you run a simple "hello world" python program as your main.py with your docker configuration?

Comment: you can try something like `python /app/main.py && sleep 600` and it will sleep for 10 minutes. Use a higher number (e.g. 3600) to sleep for longer (an hour..)